# implementing church numerals and successor function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement church numerals with javascript.(I'm fairly new to lambda calculus and functional programming in js)
this is my code for defining C0 (C0 = λs.λz.z):

```
c0 = s => z => z
```

and this is for C1 (C1 = λs.λz.sz):

```
c1 = s => z => s(z)
```

and this is for successor function (succ = λn.λs.λz.s(nsz)):

```
n => s => z => s(n(s)(z))
```

however when applying both C0 and C1 to this function the same result happens (and both are incorrect):

```
succ(c1)
-> s => z => s(n(s)(z))
succ(c0)
-> s => z => s(n(s)(z))
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that `nsz` should translate to `n(s)(z)` instead of `n(s(z))`.

Comment: When you do `succ(c0)`, you get the same result as `succ(c1)` because it gives you the string representation of the lambda function still expecting two parameters.

Comment: @MarceloCamargo so aside from changing n(s(z)) to n(s)(z) the result is correct? shouldn't it be s => z => s(z) for C0 and s => z => s(s(z)) for C1 ?

Comment: @Arya No, `C0` calls `s` zero times and `C1` calls `s` a single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Church numerals are encoded by lambdas. In order to see their effect, you must supply a function and an input. `inc` and `0` used below. Otherwise the Church numeral is an un-evaluated function. In JavaScript, when you `console.log` a function, the source code of the function is printed.

```js
const succ =
  n => s => z => s(n(s)(z))

const inc = x =>
  x + 1

const c0 =
  s => z => z

const c1 =
  succ (c0)
  
const c2 =
  succ (c1)

console .log
  ( c0 (inc) (0)        // 0
  , c1 (inc) (0)        // 1
  , c2 (inc) (0)        // 2
  , succ (c2) (inc) (0) // 3
  )
```

Above `c2` is `succ(succ(c0))`, which is Church numeral 2. Applying our Church numeral to a function, `inc`, and an input value, `0`, the function is called two (2) times. `c2 (inc) (0)` produces the same result as `inc(inc(0))`